# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Entityfarmework Core error Ubuntu

Tags: entity-framework, ubuntu, asp.net-core

Iam about to publish my ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web-Api on my Raspberry pie.
Running my application local on my Windows 10 machine works great, but when I deploy it to the Raspberry (ubuntu.16.04-arm), I have problems with entity-framework.

As soon as a databaseoperation is executed, Iam getting the following error:

> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[100100]
>         An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query for context type 'NFCDataRESTApi.SQLiteDataBase.DataBase'.
>         System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection' threw an exception. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInv                    ocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'e_sqlite3': The specified module or one of its dependencies could not be found.
>          (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
>            at SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3.NativeMethods.sqlite3_libversion_number()
>            at SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3.SQLitePCL.ISQLite3Provider.sqlite3_libversion_number()
>            at SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider(ISQLite3Provider imp)
>            at SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init()
>            --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>            at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>            at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>            at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlagsinvokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>            at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Utilities.BundleInitializer.Initialize()
>            at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection..cctor()
>            --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>            at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqliteRelationalConnection.CreateDbConnection()
>            at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.LazyRef`1.get_Value()
>            at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
>            at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqliteRelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
>            at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(Boolean buffer)
>            at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplyClass12_0`2.<Execute>b__0(DbContext c, TState s)
>            at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.NoopExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
>            at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySuccee                    ded, TState state)
>            at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
>            at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.<_TrackEntities>d__17`2.MoveNext()
>            at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection' threw an exception. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocatio                    nException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'e_sqlite3': The specified module or one of its dependencies could not be found.
>    (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
>      at SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3.NativeMethods.sqlite3_libversion_number()
>      at SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3.SQLitePCL.ISQLite3Provider.sqlite3_libversion_number()
>      at SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider(ISQLite3Provider imp)
>      at SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Utilities.BundleInitializer.Initialize()
>      at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection..cctor()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqliteRelationalConnection.CreateDbConnection()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.LazyRef`1.get_Value()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqliteRelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(Boolean buffer)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.<Execute>b__0(DbContext c, TState s)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.NoopExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded, TState state)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.<_TrackEntities>d__17`2.MoveNext()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
>   fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
>         Connection id "0HL8JR800T0MD", Request id "0HL8JR800T0MD:00000003": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection' threw an exception. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'e_sqlite3': The specified module or one of its dependencies could not be found.
>    (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
>      at SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3.NativeMethods.sqlite3_libversion_number()
>      at SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3.SQLitePCL.ISQLite3Provider.sqlite3_libversion_number()
>      at SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider(ISQLite3Provider imp)
>      at SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Utilities.BundleInitializer.Initialize()
>      at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection..cctor()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqliteRelationalConnection.CreateDbConnection()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.LazyRef`1.get_Value()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqliteRelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(Boolean buffer)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.<Execute>b__0(DbContext c, TState s)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.NoopExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded, TState state)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.<_TrackEntities>d__17`2.MoveNext()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
>      at NFCDataRESTApi.Repositories.PermissionRepository.GetAdminUsers() in C:\Users\morit\Desktop\NFCRESTApi\RESTApi\RESTApi\Repositories\PermissionRepository.cs:line 28
>      at NFCDataRESTApi.Filters.ValidateUserFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) in C:\Users\morit\Desktop\NFCRESTApi\RESTApi\RESTApi\Filters\ValidateUserFilter.cs:line 27
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__10.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__14.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__22.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope&scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__17.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__15.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame`1.d__2.MoveNext()

The intersting part probably is:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'e_sqlite3': The specified module or one of its dependencies could not be found.
```

Iam using entity framework core

Any advices?

Edit:

My csproj:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCL.raw" Version="0.9.4-pre1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="2.0.0" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: did you install EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite via Nuget?

Comment: Actually, my application was targeting core 1.0, but I migrated it to 2.0. However, I did not have to install EF-Core. It Just worked. Do I have to install something via nuget, to get it working? I edited my question, you can see my packages now.

Comment: *It is installed, seems like its a dependency from another packaged

Comment: probably you need to run `dotnet restore` on your ubuntu or smth like that. did you just copy your project from windows to ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, Iam building the application on my windows machine and put it on my ubuntu via FTP. I cant run dotnet restore on my ubuntu, since the arm processor architecture doesnt support dot net core yet. I can only host it on my ubuntu, building is impossible. However I run dotnet restore on my windows machine before deploying.

Comment: i afraid that it will not work in this way. have you tried to setup vm with ubuntu, build project there and copy it to raspberry? and why do you think asp.net core will work on arm, while building project on arm isn't possible?

Comment: I remeber reading that building is not possible.. not sure about the source tho. But the frontend and every other piece of logic is working perfect, besides the database operation. I will try out your hint with building the application on a ubuntu machine in move it to my pie, thank you :)

Comment: hope this will help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if dotnet restore didn't work: possibly you need local/linux libraries on which the nuget package depends on?

You can install sqllite through app-get. Allthough i don't think this would be necessary. But I had http/ssl issues before on dotnet docker image, i had to install extra linux libraries.

try this: https://iqbalnaved.wordpress.com/2014/07/10/how-to-install-sqlite-3-8-2-on-ubuntu-14-04-and-commands-for-creating-database-and-tables/